# Unable to insert elements correctly using FIFO LinkedList Java

Tags: java, linked-list

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with the below code insertq method: Works fine when I just have 2 inputs 10 and 20. 
With insert method I am able to correctly insert data ,however its LIFO.I am trying to do FIFO here.
I wan to insert multiple elements in list  and want to display in FIFO format .

```
/**
 * LinkedList
 * @author ashish
 *
 */

class Node {
    int data;
     Node next;
     Node(int data) {
         this.data = data;
     }
}

public class LinkedList {
    static Node root;
    Node temp = null;

    public void insert(int data) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node(data);
        }
        else {
            temp = root;
            root = new Node(data);
            root.next = temp;
        }
    } // end of insert

    public void insertq(int data) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node(data);
        }
        else {
            temp = root;
    //      temp.next = new Node(data);
    //      root = temp;
            root = new Node(data);
            temp.next = root;
            root = temp;
        }
    } // end of insert

    public void display(Node node) {
        while (node != null) {
            System.out.println(node.data);
            node = node.next;
        }
    }

    /**
      * @param args
      */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    //    list.insert(10);
    //    list.insert(20);
    //    list.insert(30);
    //    list.insertq(10);
//Insert Data
        list.insertq(20);
        list.insertq(30);
        list.insertq(40);
    //    list.insert(10);
    //    list.insert(20);
    //  list.insert(30);
        list.display(root);
    }
}
```

Comment: include explicit examples of what you'd like to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to insert at the end of the list, you either need to traverse the list till you reach the last element or have the reference to the tail of the list to avoid the above.

To implement point 1,

```
public void insertq(int data) {
    if(root == null) {
      root = new Node(data);
    } else {
      temp = root;
      while (temp.next != null) {
          temp = temp.next;
      }
      Node newNode = new Node(data);
      temp.next = newNode;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `insertq()` method is that it is doing a LIFO insertion strategy.  You already have a method which will insert using a FIFO strategy, and that is just the plain `insert()` method.  So, use `insert()` if you want to iterate your list in a FIFO order.

I tested `insert` with the following code and verified that in fact it is displaying using LIFO order, starting from the root:

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
list.insert(10);
list.insert(20);
list.insert(30);
list.insert(40);
list.insert(50);
list.display(list.root);

50
40
30
20
10
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me :

```
/**
 * LinkedList
 * @author ashish
 *
 */

class Node
{
  int data;
  Node next;
  Node(int data)
  {
    this.data=data;
  }
}
public class LinkedList {

  static Node root;
  Node temp=null;
  public void insert(int data)
  {
    if(root==null)
    {
      root=new Node(data);
    }
    else
    {
      temp=root;
      root=new Node(data);
      root.next=temp;
    }
  }//end of insert


  public void insertq(int data)
  {
    if(root==null)
    {
      root=new Node(data);
    }
    else
    {
      temp=root;
      while(temp.next!=null)
      {
        temp=temp.next;
      }
      Node newNode=new Node(data);
      temp.next=newNode;
    }
  }//end of insert

  public void display(Node node)
  {
    while(node!=null)
    {
      System.out.println(node.data);
      node=node.next;
    }
  }
  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList list=new LinkedList();
  //  list.insert(10);
   // list.insert(20);
    //list.insert(30);
    list.insertq(10);
    list.insertq(20);
    list.insertq(30);
    list.insertq(40);
//    list.insert(10);
//    list.insert(20);
//  list.insert(30);
    list.display(root);
  }

}
```